# Help with SOQL Query to fetch all records with a combination of where and Limit

Tags: soql, query, governorlimits, set, nested

I am new to Salesforce . I'm faciing an issue to form a query to use it in a Apex class .

```
Example Query : 
   /*Set with all the LookupField__c lookup field id's */
         Set<Id> LookupField  = new Set<Id>();


List<Classified_Field_Log__c > Classified_Field_Log =  select Id, Name ,few fields ., from Classified_Field_Log__c where LookupField__c in : LookupField   order by createddate desc limit 1
```

Explanation:
LookupField__c  = Lookup Field

- There will be multiple Lookup Fields , Therefore i will be using something like set
- There will be multiple records with this lookup field
- I need only the latest record with This Lookup Field.
  Example LookupField__c  values  :
  Credit , Debit , Saving.

Issue : I am getting only 1 record , since the limit is 1 .

Required Out put : I need 3 Latest records one each with these 3 Lookup Fields (based on created date)

Any suggestion is appreciated , Thankyou .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your query on the lookup object, not on `Classified_Field_Log__c`.

```sql
SELECT Id, 
  (SELECT Id, <some other fields> FROM Classified_Field_Log__c ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1)
  FROM Lookup_Object__c WHERE Id IN :lookupField
```

Comment: This worked , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would need three queries:

```
List<Classified_Field_Log__c > Latest1 = [select Id, ... FROM Classified_Field_Log__c WHERE LookupField_1__c in : LookupField ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];
List<Classified_Field_Log__c > Latest2 = [select Id, ... FROM Classified_Field_Log__c WHERE LookupField_2__c in : LookupField ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];
List<Classified_Field_Log__c > Latest3 = [select Id, ... FROM Classified_Field_Log__c WHERE LookupField_3__c in : LookupField ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];
```

Since you can have a max of 40 lookup fields, that should be well under the query limit

Comment: Hi , I have only one lookup field , only the values changes.  In the Set I have values .    We will have multiple records with the same lookup value. We need only the latest record based on created date .